# Android app connect php file and conditional simple

Tags: php, android, json

I need my android app connect to a PHP file (just does a select on the table and displays the result in JSON format) How I connect my app to php file and make an conditional? for example:

JSON:

```
{"productos":[{"codeqr":"hola","actions":[]}
```

Condicional:

```
if (ResultPHP==hola){
 //se encontró correctamente 'hola'
}else{
 //no se encontró 'hola'
}
```

At the moment, My code to connect is:

```
 public class QRpost {

 public static void postData() {
 // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("qr.php");
 try {
   // Execute HTTP Post Request
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
   try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    webs.close();
   }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error al convertir el resultado");
   }
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }
  }
 }
```

Can anybody help me? Sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

After creating your `BufferedReader` you will need to read each line into a `StringBuilder`

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            builder.append(line);
        }

        webs.close();

        String json = builder.toString();
```

The `json` variable will then contain all of your JSON as a `String`. Then you will need to use a JSON parser on that string to get the variables you need out of the JSON. Look at `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` for how to parse a string.